# Jersey 2 filter value for field with Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, filter, properties, jersey-2.0

I need to know if it's possible to fill a value using spring's @Value mechanism into a Jersey 2 filter (@Provider)

```
@Provider
public class AppConfigFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Value("${some.prop.key}")
    private String aValue;
    // class implementation
}
```

Comment: Did you make it a Spring bean by adding `@Component`?

Comment: Thanks @PaulSamsotha, that just worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming proper settings (spring, jersey 2, etc), adding @Component works and it doesn't produce conflict/duplicate instanciation.

```
@Provider
@Component
public class AppConfigFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Value("${some.prop.key}")
    private String aValue;
    // class implementation
}
```